# "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folder" Option Not Visible in Multisite

Tags: multisite, media-library

For whatever reason, I can't see the "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folder" checkbox in `Settings > Media`.
I'm using WordPress multisite with sub-directories, and it's a fresh installation. I tried deactivating all plugins, and the theme is "Twenty Twenty-one", but I still can't see the checkbox.

I guess it's related to multisite, because the other WordPress (single installation) I have on my host shows the checkbox.

(I'm using WordPress 5.8 + MultiSite)

Comment: Indeed this option isn't present in the UI on multisite installs

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks! Maybe it'll be better to send this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

All credit to: https://chiroiu.com/blog/disable-month-year-based-uploads-on-wordpress-multisite/

**Disable month- / year-based uploads on wordpress multisite
Wordpress / January 30, 2020**
By default wordpress organises uploaded media into month- and year-based folders. Probably a relict from when it was mostly used as a blogging tool. You can disable this easily enough under Settings > Media.

On a WordPress Multisite installation there is no such option. You have to change the setting on the network page itself – so only Super-Admins can do this. As I end up searching for it every freakin’ time here you go:

As Super-Admin go to the multisite’s network into the “Sites” menu and choose edit for the specific site.

Go to “Settings”

Search for “Uploads Use Yearmonth Folders” and set it to 0

Scroll all the way to the bottom and hit “Save changes”